# Javafx accordion with transparent background?

Tags: background, javafx, accordion

Somehow accordion seems to behave differently than the other javafx elements, cause I cannot make its background transparent with CSS.

I found a hint somewhere with this:

```
.accordion.titled-pane > *.content {
   -fx-background-color: null;
}
```

But it didn't work. Maybe the syntax, I don't know, I tried without the > and * too...

My try was doing the same as with panels, so:

```
#leftTop{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(237, 243, 245, 0.8);
}
```

I set the fx:id. It doesn't work either. I made this with all the child nodes the same too, that are "above" the accordion itself, so with the titled pane and the anchor pane that is on the titled pane. The colouring part has its effect but not the transparency.

I have read that javafx had issues, but that comment was from 2013...

Do you know a solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a space between `.accordion` and `.titled-pane` (the `TitledPane` is a child node of `Accordion`; without the space you are trying to match a single node that has both the style class `accordion` and the style class `titled-pane`):

```
.accordion .titled-pane > *.content{
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
}
```

Note that if you want the title portion of the titled pane transparent, you can do that with

```
.accordion .titled-pane .title {
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
}
```

Comment: that's great, thanks. can you recommend good structured materials for learning this on my own? I mostly find html related css guides...