# JavaFX accordion effect

Tags: java, css, javafx, styles, effect

I tried to apply styling to an accordion pane and faced a problem.

This does not work.

```
accordion.setEffect(new DropShadow(BlurType.ONE_PASS_BOX, Color.BLACK, 8, 0, 2, 0));
```

This(style.css) also did not work.

```
.accordion{
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , black , 8 , 0.0 , 2 , 0 );
}
```

Now it looks like this...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzv2a.png)

But I want the shadow like under this table-view...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE92Z.png)

I tried to search for a solution on the internet but I didnt find anything!

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks for your answers!

P.S.

This variants don't work too:

```
.accordion .pane{
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , black , 8 , 0.0 , 2 , 0 );
}

.accordion .titled-pane{
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , black , 8 , 0.0 , 2 , 0 );
}

.accordion .titled-pane .title{
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , black , 8 , 0.0 , 2 , 0 );
}

.accordion .titled-pane > *.content{
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , black , 8 , 0.0 , 2 , 0 );
}

.accordion > .titled-pane > .content{
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , black , 8 , 0.0 , 2 , 0 );
}
```

Comment: Could you add an image of what style you are aiming for? (And preferably also an image of what you get right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrapped it in Pane and use "dropshadow" to the pane. I did not find another way out...

Answer (score 0):

The accordion is a layout so you need to access to the components of this layout that you wish to change (`content` / `titled-pane` / `title`), the most apparent is the `titled-pane`. as mentioned before in another question, here [James_D answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038701/javafx-accordion-with-transparent-background), and referring to the building of the `Accordion` in the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/accordion-titledpane.htm).

Comment: Thaks for your answer! But, unfortunatly, it does not work.